# Validation RegExp Issue

Tags: javascript, regex

I know there are lots of questions related to validation but, after looking at so many on SO I can't seem to fix this what so ever.

I'm trying to match a postcode to a regular expression I have found on SO. The fiddle says the postcode is invalid, yet when I test the regular expression on rubular.com it works fine

[image: Rubular Image]

JS Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/aeqawadv/1/

```
<div id="test"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var string = "SK13 6NT";
    var ukPostcode = new RegExp(/^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2} ?[0-9][A-Z]{2}$i/);
    if (ukPostcode.test(string)) {
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML="Valid";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML="Invalid";
    }
</script>
```

Any ideas? I've also tried match() as oppose to test()

**EDIT**

Just realised I was using rubular instead of scriptular but, result is still the same

Answer (score 1):

You have an "i" after your dollar-sign at the end of it.

```
var ukPostcode = new RegExp(/^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2} ?[0-9][A-Z]{2}$i/);
```

should be

```
var ukPostcode = new RegExp(/^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2} ?[0-9][A-Z]{2}$/);
```

or (if you were aiming for case-insensitivity)

```
var ukPostcode = new RegExp(/^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2} ?[0-9][A-Z]{2}$/i);
```

Comment: Or maybe it was supposed to be a case insensitive flag. Then the `i` should appear after the second `/`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `i` after your end of string `$` anchor, and why not use a regular expression literal?

```
var ukPostcode = /^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2} ?[0-9][A-Z]{2}$/
```

If `i` was supposed to be used as the case-insensitive modifier, place it after your delimiter.

```
var ukPostcode = /^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2} ?[0-9][A-Z]{2}$/i
```